# Expectation Value of an Operator in the Projector Augmented Wave Method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body, quantum-chemistry, density-functional-theory

[image]

I'm starting on DFT and came across this technique called **PAW Wave Method** for multi atoms system wave function. It is a widely employed method in DFT calculations.

From the attached picture, I'm trying to arrive at the last equation by direct substitution of the first equation into the 2nd last equation. My question is why the sign turned out to be negative instead of positive, and what happened to the cross term between $\phi$ and $\tilde{\phi}$?

Comment: You should use MathJax to include equations.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation is valid for the Frozen-Core Approximation. More information can be found in this text, up till section 1.3:

C. Rostgaard, "The Projector Augmented-wave Method", [arXiv:0910.1921](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1921).